# How filter datatable using Like same SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, filter, datatable

In sql server, I have a query: 
`SELECT * FROM [tableName] WHERE [colName] LIKE '%abc[xyz]%'`.

It same query:

```
SELECT * FROM [tableName] WHERE [colName] LIKE '%abcx%' OR [colName] LIKE '%abcy%' OR [colName] LIKE '%abcz%'
```

In C#, I using DataTable.SELECT("colName LIKE '%abc[xyz]%'") => error.

How resolve it?

Comment: What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: you cannot have "[" or "]" in your query. why you don't use the same where statement you have in the first query?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using linq?
With linq you could write:

```
Datatable.Select(x=>x.ColName.Contains("abcx.ColName")||x.ColName.Contains("abcy")||x.ColName.Contains("abcz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable.SELECT("colName LIKE '%abcx%' OR colName LIKE '%abcy%' OR colName LIKE '%abcz%'")
```